# PHP MySQLi loop through all rows in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

so I have a MySQL database table with the following contents:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
| id | username | created_at          | name  | time-start       | time-end         | comments |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|  1 | test     | 2022-11-29 20:23:06 | test  | 2022-11-29T22:22 | 2022-11-29T13:23 | NULL     |
|  2 | test     | 2022-11-29 20:36:51 | test1 | 2022-11-29T22:23 | 2022-11-29T14:12 | NULL     |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

I have some code that runs a query on the database:

```
<?php
            require_once "connect.php";
            session_start();

            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $sql = "SELECT `name`, `time-start`, `time-end` FROM `reminders` WHERE username = '$username';";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))){
            
                echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
            }
                
        ?>
```

I expect this to code to loop over the results and echo both of the names from the database. Like this:

```
test
test1
```

But, instead, i get this:

```
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest.....
```

If anyone knows how to fix, that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Every time your while loop executes, you are executing your query _again_. The `mysqli_query` does not belong nested into your loop condition like that, it needs to happen _once_ before the loop.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: Why are you using mysqli? Why aren't you using PDO? It would be much easier for you. Also, using `while` loop like this can be confusing, why aren't you using `foreach` here instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to only execute `mysqli_query` once outside the loop and it works now:

```
<?php
    require_once "connect.php";
    session_start();

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $sql = "SELECT `name`, `time-start`, `time-end` FROM `reminders` WHERE username = '$username';";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // var_dump($row);
        echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
    }

?>
```